# ImageGrab.grab(bbox) and Image.getpixel() Used together

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

While using the grab function from `PIL.ImageGrab`, there's a parameter called `bbox`, which specifies the bounding box of which the screengrab should be taken. And when I want to get the value of a specific pixel, what should the coordinates be?
For example:

```
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(500, 500, 600, 700)
print(im.getpixel(510, 510))
print(im.getpixel(10, 10))
```

Both the statements give me an error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've made two mistakes:

1. Since you've specified a bounding box, the resulting image is smaller than your screen resolution. The bounding box is a `(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y)` tuple, so with the values `(500, 500, 600, 700)`, the image has a width of 100 pixels and a height of 200 pixels.

   That explains why `im.getpixel(510, 510)` doesn't work - the coordinate 510 is outside of the image.
2. The [`getpixel` method](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=getpixel#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel) takes the coordinates as a `(x, y)` tuple, not as two separate arguments. The correct syntax is `im.getpixel((10, 10))`.