# Image index out of Range, except it shouldn't be

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, win32gui

I am setting an application that needs to take a screencap of a particular window. I've used some code I found to get the position and size of the window and it seems to have worked, according to Line 26's output it is working just fine. But when I attempt to get any pixel from the corresponding bbox (bounding box), even (1,1), it will output `IndexError: image index out of range` even though the window size is definitely larger than 1,1 as evidenced by Line 26's output. How can I solve this issue, and why does it seem to be out of range?

```
import PIL.ImageGrab as IG
import win32gui
x = 0
y = 0
w = 0
h = 0
def callback(hwnd, extra):
    if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) == "Window": #replace window with whatever you like for testing
        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        global x
        global y
        global w
        global h
        x = rect[0]
        y = rect[1]
        w = rect[2] - x
        h = rect[3] - y

def main():
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

print(x,y,w,h) #DEBUG
screen = IG.grab(bbox=(x,y,w,h))
print(screen.getpixel((1,1)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageGrab.grab(bbox) and Image.getpixel() Used together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479552/imagegrab-grabbbox-and-image-getpixel-used-together)

Answer (score 0):

I've realized the problem now; The bounding box consists not of X Y Width and Height but the coordinates of the top left and bottom right of the bounding box. This meant that the size of the bounding box was negative, thus the problem.