# How to get the x, y coordinates of center of a contour area and move the mouse there or store the coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I use the ImageGrab bbox to capture a part of the screen (real time video), I make a mask for contours, I use moments to get the center of the contour area, until now works fine.
Now I need to get x, y of the center of the contour when a event is triggered and save the coordinates, and when the center of the contour pass the same coordinates again trigger another event.

```
for cnt in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > 500:
        # I want to know the coordinates of intersection of the lines 
        cv2.rectangle(# rectangle on the contour area)
        cv2.line( # horizontal line)
        cv2.line(# vertical line)
        # I want to follow the coordinates of the cv2.circle on screen  
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        X = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        Y = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        cv2.circle(frame, (X, Y), 13, (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

The x, y of the cv2.moments give 2 int values, but if send the mouse move to that values, the mouse is not follow the cv2.circle on the screen, is way off.

Comment: I guess this is some kind of coordinate discrepancy between the image and the screen. Maybe [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479552) help you.

Comment: Thanks @HansHirse, you right, I adjust top left to 0 and works fine.