# OpenCV VideoWriter Fails to Write with Coordinates Given

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a screen recorder project where I capture frame with PIL.
The program works fine if I set the coordinates of bbox to 0 and 0, but if I change them, the VideoWriter function writes nothing. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import cv2
fcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
output=cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fcc,20.0,(500,500))
while 1:
    img=ig.grab(bbox=(20,20,500,500))
    imn=np.array(img)
    imf=cv2.cvtColor(imn,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow('Output',imf)
    output.write(imf)
    if cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: [`VideoWriter` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59) takes a size, not a bounding box.

Comment: Apparently, the frame size of the output file does not match frame size of ImageGrab. I've updated the code, still no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions of the bounding box must match the video frame size.

The video frame size set by `cv2.VideoWriter` is `(500,500)`.
The bounding box size must be 500x500.

`bbox` tuple format is `(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y)` - the last two arguments are right_x and bottom_y and not width and height (it's actually right_x+1 and bottom_y+1).
See: [ImageGrab.grab(bbox) and Image.getpixel() Used together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479552/imagegrab-grabbbox-and-image-getpixel-used-together).

The correct code is:

```
img = ig.grab(bbox=(20, 20, 520, 520))
```

---

One more issue:

You must call `output.release()` in order to properly close the recorded video file.

---

Here is a complete code sample:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import cv2

cols, rows = 500, 500

fcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fcc, 20.0, (cols,rows))

while True:
    #img = ig.grab(bbox=(20,20,500,500))  #bbox = (left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479552/imagegrab-grabbbox-and-image-getpixel-used-together
    left_x = 20
    top_y = 20
    right_x = left_x + cols
    bottom_y = top_y + rows
    img = ig.grab(bbox=(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y))

    imn = np.array(img)
    imf = cv2.cvtColor(imn, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow('Output', imf)
    output.write(imf)
    if cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('q'):
        break

output.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```